# App slows down device even if it is in background or not running

Tags: android, performance, galaxy

I am developing an Android App with `minSDK 18 and targetSDK 23.`

All of my real devices and emulate run normally if the app is installed but my Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo slows down in it is installed.

The UI only reacts slowly using several apps even if my App is not running or only running in background. Which tools can I use for analysing this?

For what reasons may the performance be affected? What do I have to look for exactly?

Comment: Is your app having any of these GPS/maps/location services??

Comment: quick fix : go to setting > application manager> ALL teb > open up context menu >Reset app preference , do it and run your app ,let me know if still face this issue .

Comment: @Radhe: No this doesn't help. I've already reinstalled the app several times. I don't want to know how to fix this from a user point of view. I wanted to now how to analyze this behaviour in code and in some android tools.